# SASS, Compass and Bootstrap with Angular js? Can they work together?

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, sass, compass-sass

There is a lot of talk that SASS and Twitter Bootstrap wont work together!

From what I have read, Bootstrap, Angular and AngularUI all work really well together! However people at work are saying that we cant't use Bootstrap with SASS?

I have no experience with SASS and Compass so I want to ask you guys will all the above work? As we all want to use Bootstrap and Angular as we have heard and read good things!

Will introducing SASS be an issue or can they all work seamlessly together? I just want to know why etc because I think people are telling me wrong information and I want expert opinions from people who have actually used it, so I can fight my corner!

Thanks

Comment: Why shouldn't they? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#sass Angular: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 2):

Sass doesn't really affect any framework other than it is a preprocessor that ends up in a (CSS3) compliant stylesheet...so it doesn't matter what you use (and that is the point of Sass really)

And as already mentioned there is a Sass version....but you can still use Sass with the bog standard version too.